# Android - Allow dialog in horizontal orientation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, screen-orientation

I have an activity which is locked in portrait orientation.
When i show the dialog from this activity, I can't turn the screen in the horizontal view.

My question: 
Can I do this without changing the activity orientation?
Thanks